# How do I define a Terraform var that has a string and a map of key:value tags to put into cloud resources?

Tags: variables, key, terraform

I am trying to define a reusable template for use with AWS resources, and one of the things I need to do is declare vars for resources that include values as well as a key:value map for use with tags. For example, a vpc has a CIDR_BLOCK string and a TAGS var. The tags can be empty or have as many key:value tags as AWS will allow. However, I can't to figure out why it doesn't work.

```
variable vpc {
  type = list(object({
    cidr_block = string,
    tags = map (list(string))
  }))
  default = [
    "10.30.0.0/16",
    { aTag = "aValue" }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, if I understand the question correctly, you want the CIDR blocks to have associated tags, is that correct? If so, your example is only missing curly-braces, object keys and your map should probably just be of `string` values, so

```
variable vpc {
  type = list(object({
    cidr_block = string,
    tags = map(string)
  }))

  default = [
   {
      cidr_block = "10.30.0.0/16",
      tags = { aTag = "aValue" }
   }
  ]
}
```

So, to enumerate the changes

- `tags` type is `map(string)` rather than `map(list(string))` since each key should have one value
- Add curly braces to the default object
- Add object keys to the default object

If you meant to provided the `cidr_blocks` and `tags` separately, you will need to define multiple variables.

Comment: Yes, what I want is to create a template for reuse, with objects that can have x number of tags as necessary. I was planning to remove the atag = "avalue" so that anyone using the template can define whatever tags are needed, and later on define default tags depending on other vars in the project. Thanks!